# Redirect product SKU from Url to the related product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, sku

I have a WooCommerce store and I would like to basically redirect product SKU from Url to the related product.

So for example for the Url `domain.com/product/SKUID`, user should be redirected to the following url `domain.com/product/product-name` or should open up the product page.

I tried this plugin [SKU Shortlink for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sku-shortlink-for-woocommerce/) but it ended up breaking my whole website making "too many redirects" issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need any plugin for that… You can use the following custom simple function hooked in `template_redirect` action hook, that will redirect from `domain.com/product/SKUID` to the related WooCommerce product single page.

The code use built in function `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` to retrieve the product ID from the product sku.

Then If the product sku matches with an existing product, user is redirected to the product single page.

The code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'sku_product_redirect');
function sku_product_redirect() {
    // Get the sku string from Url
    $sku = get_query_var('product');
    
    if ( ! empty( $sku ) ) {
        // Get the product Id from a product sku string
        $product_id = (int) wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
        
        if( $product_id > 0 ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink($product_id) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hey LoicTheAztec, this seems to not work in the current woocommerce version, any idea what changed?

Comment: Same problem, not working get_query_var, so I solved  with this: `if ( is_product() ) { $productObject = wc_get_product(get_queried_object_id()); `